# variable is redefined in augment assignment if it is used in closure

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is the example:

```py
def foo1():
    res = 0
    def foo2():
        nonlocal res
        res += 10
        return 20

    rv = foo2()
    res += rv

    print(res)

foo1()  # output: 30
```

`res` is increased by 10 in closure, becoming 10, then plus 10 returned by `foo2`, resulting in 20 consequently. So far, so good.

Here is an another similar case:

```py
def foo1():
    res = 0
    def foo2():
        nonlocal res
        res += 10
        return 20

    res += foo2()

    print(res)

foo1()  # output: 20
```

Strangely, it outputs 10.

It seems that `res` is re-defined in `res += foo2()`. Do I think right?

Why is the result 10 at above example? what results in this?

- CPython 3.6.9

Comment: `res += foo2()` means `res = res + foo2()`, but you want  `res = foo2() + res`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the symptom, in stack pseudo-code it is acting like

> push res, push foo2(), add, pop res

So the change to `res` in the middle of `foo2` has no effect on the result. Because it "grabbed" the value of `res` BEFORE `foo2`, and used that in the expression.

Or you could show the pseudo-code like this:

```
temp1 = res
temp2 = foo2()
temp1 = temp1 + temp2
res = temp1
```